# R studio ggplot() has different colors for geom_point() and geom_bar()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to make two graphs: a geom_point() graph and a geom_bar() graph.

All of my data is characterized by groups 1-4, and this group number is what I'm using to color in my points as well as my bar lines.

Here is the code for my graphs:

```
ggplot(all_data, aes(Mean, total)) + 
   geom_point(size=0.5, color = all_data$group)


ggplot(attribute_data, aes(x=attribute,
                       y=attribute_value,
                       fill=factor(attribute_group))) +
   geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity") + 
   coord_flip() +
   ggtitle("Characterization")
```

While I am looking at different aspects of the data in each graph, I need the colors for each group to be the same in both graphs. The groups are the same in each data file. However, I'm getting different colors for the groups when I plot each graph. How do I get the colors to be the same? Am I missing something simple?

Here is some example code:

```
 id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
 mean <- c(13,23,42,53,64,75,75,8)
 total <- c(52,34,23,15,14,62,16,12)
 group <- c(3,2,1,4,3,2,2,1)

 df1 <- data.frame(id,mean,total,group)

 attribute <- c("round",
           "square",
           "round",
           "square",
           "round",
           "square",
           "round",
           "square"
 )
 value <- c(14,
                 13,
                 55,
                 76,
                 46,
                 3,
                 5,
                 6)
 attribute_group <- c(1,
                   1,
                   2,
                   2,
                   3,
                   3,
                   4,
                   4)
 df2 <- data.frame()

 ggplot(df1, aes(mean, total, color=group)) + 
 geom_point(size=3)


 ggplot(df2, aes(x=attribute,
                       y=value,
                       fill=factor(attribute_group))) +
 geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity") + 
 coord_flip() +
 ggtitle("Characterization")
```

Comment: In your scatterplot, you're not mapping the `all_data$group` variable to a scale (because it is not inside `aes()`), whereas you do map it to a scale in the barplot (by setting `aes(fill = ...)`.

Comment: As a first thing to try, put `color = group` in the `aes()` call of the first graph - don't use `color = all_data$group`. If this isn't solving things, to post some code for us to try out.

Comment: I corrected my code to: ggplot(all_data_2019, aes(Mean, total, color=group)) + 
  geom_point(size=0.5), but now I'm just getting a gradient of blues which makes it extremely hard to differentiate groups and also doesn't match the bar plot colors.

Comment: If you were able to post some sample data we could help build a working solution. You need the two columns -- `group` and `attribute_group` -- to be factors with the same levels in the same order. Then `ggplot` will default to plotting/colouring them the same.

Comment: I made up a dataset that wasn't the same as mine because it's huge, but it is the same format. I added it to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap both `aes(color = group)` and `aes(fill = attribute_group)` in each graph in the same `factor` function and pass the same set of `levels` then that should ensure that they're both plotted as discrete colours and in the same order/mapping:

```r
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(df1, aes(mean, total, color=factor(group, levels = 1:4))) + 
  geom_point(size=3) +
  scale_colour_discrete("Groups")
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(df2, aes(x=attribute,
                y=value,
                fill=factor(attribute_group, levels = 1:4))) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity") + 
  coord_flip() +
  ggtitle("Characterization") +
  scale_fill_discrete("Groups")
```

[image]

Comment: Great that it worked! Do mark as question closed :)